# How to set Moodle course custom fields via command line?

Tags: php, moodle

I want to set course custom fields via command line. To do this I first wanted to print all existing custom fields (from Site administration > Courses > Course custom fields) with a command like this:

```
php /admin/cli/cfg.php --component=core_customfield
```

But it returns nothing in the terminal. I tried different component names but none of them showed any output. I learned this approach to modify settings, but I don't know if it's even applicable here.

Did I miss the correct component name?

Is there a list of all component names I can access?

Is this approach even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you have used is for outputting the configuration values stored in the database tables mdl_config (for core settings, without a 'component') or mdl_config_plugins (for plugin settings, where a 'component' is specified).

The details of custom course fields are not stored in this way - they have their own database table mdl_customfield_field (with the per-course values stored in mdl_customfiled_data). These cannot be accessed using the command you have listed.

I'm not aware of any built-in Moodle CLI script that will list course custom fields - you would need to either write such a script yourself or manually run an SQL statement against your database to extract them.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I feel like I got a better understanding of how it works. I will write a script to access and write the custom fields.